# T-SQL command to get only rows that can CAST()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a DB of raw data that has everything as varchar, one of the columns contains a price, which for the most part would convert into FLOAT easily. However, there are a few rows that have trash in that column with a bunch of characters and would not convert to float.

Is there a way to select only that rows that would convert to float (i.e. only the ones taht actually have a number)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: It is important to include the `+ 'e0'` in the numeric test, as things like `'+'`, `'$'`, `'.'` and `'3e8'` would otherwise all return 1.

```
SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(YourColumn + 'e0') = 1
```

Comment: [It is also important to not assume that the `WHERE` will happen before the `CAST`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors). The OP would still need to use `CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(YourColumn + 'e0') = 1 THEN CAST(YourColumn AS FLOAT) END` in the `SELECT` list to avoid the possibility of invalid cast errors.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the ISNUMERIC function?

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
where ISNUMERIC(column)=1
```

See [ISNUMERIC()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ISNUMERIC function first, and only when it is numeric apply the CAST.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're on SQL Server 2012+ and `ISNUMERIC()` is giving you fits, you can use [`TRY_PARSE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) which allows you to specify the exact data type.

```
WHERE TRY_PARSE(price_col AS FLOAT) IS NOT NULL
```

As an aside, you should not be using imprecise data types for currency.  You should be using NUMERIC, DECIMAL, or MONEY.